# Extra product tab options in Magento2

Tags: magento2

Is there a better way to guarantee a sale then to provide your user with every detail. how Apply Extra Product Tabs to give users an additional information about the product or service offering.

Comment: Specify your requirement in details.

Answer (score 0):

I have used "Extra Product Tabs" extension and it has worked for me. Hope this solves your problem.
[enter link description here](https://addify.co/product/magento-2-product-tabs/)